# How can itext7 remove the space between paragraph text and paragraph top?

Tags: .net-core, itext7, c#-6.0

Using itext7, I created a pdf with two paragraphs.

```
string cardPdf = "card.pdf"; float cardWidth = 266.5f; float cardHeight = 164.4f;
using (PdfDocument cardDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(cardPdf)))
using (Document doc = new Document(cardDoc))
{
    PdfPage page = cardDoc.AddNewPage(new iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize(cardWidth, cardHeight));
    Paragraph pg1 = new Paragraph("WriteParagraph 1").SetFontSize(10f);
    pg1.SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.YELLOW);
    doc.Add(pg1);
    Paragraph pg2 = new Paragraph("WriteParagraph 2").SetFontSize(20f);
    pg2.SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.YELLOW);
    doc.Add(pg2);
}
```

I found that there are gaps at the top of the paragraph text and the background rectangle, and different font sizes cause different gaps. How can I remove the spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of those methods to reduce space around to document.

**Document Level**

```cs
SetMargins(float topMargin, float rightMargin, float bottomMargin, float leftMargin);

SetTopMargin(float topMargin);
SetRightMargin(float rightMargin);
SetBottomMargin(float bottomMargin);
SetLeftMargin(float leftMargin);
```

**Paragraph Level**

```cs
SetMargins(float topMargin, float rightMargin, float bottomMargin, float leftMargin);

SetMarginTop(float topMargin);
SetMarginRight(float rightMargin);
SetMarginBottom(float bottomMargin);
SetMarginLeft(float leftMargin);
```

To control line spacing/leading for the paragraph.

```cs
SetMultipliedLeading(float leadingValue);
```

If need to control leading on overall document level.

```cs
SetProperty(int property, object value);

SetProperty(Property.LEADING, new Leading(Leading.MULTIPLIED, float leading Value);
```

Try this:

```cs
string cardPdf = "card.pdf"; float cardWidth = 266.5f; float cardHeight = 164.4f;
using (PdfDocument cardDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(cardPdf)))
using (Document doc = new Document(cardDoc))
{
    doc.SetMargins(15f, 20f, 15f, 20f);
    PdfPage page = cardDoc.AddNewPage(new iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize(cardWidth, cardHeight));
    Paragraph pg1 = new Paragraph("WriteParagraph 1").SetFontSize(10f);
    pg1.SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.YELLOW);
    pg1.SetMultipliedLeading(0.8f);
    doc.Add(pg1);
    Paragraph pg2 = new Paragraph("WriteParagraph 2").SetFontSize(20f);
    pg2.SetMultipliedLeading(0.8f);
    pg2.SetMarginTop(0f);
    pg2.SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.YELLOW);
    doc.Add(pg2);
}
```

Comment: It solved my problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that the value of 0.8 is font related. Is there any way to find the relationship between them?

Comment: Example on Alignment, Indentation, Leading and Spacing.
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/alignment-indentation-leading-and-spacing-in-cells

Here is official documentation with Examples.
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples